# The onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) does not work in a custom View

Tags: android

I wrote the following code. I want when I touch only the `rectangle` object as the result I see the `larger_rectangle` object.But when I want to touch only using the `rectangle` object, I can not see the `larger_rectangle` object on the screen. Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Rectangle rectangle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        rectangle = new Rectangle(this);
        setContentView(rectangle);

    }

}

class Rectangle extends View {
    Paint paint;

    Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    new Larger_Rectangle(getContext());

    return true;
}
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(10, 30, 50, 70, paint);
    }

}

 class Larger_Rectangle extends View {
    Paint paint;

    Larger_Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(60,100,120,150,paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: "`new Larger_Rectangle(getContext());`" what is it for?

Comment: Because I want when I touch **only and only** the `rectangle` object, I see the `larger_rectangle` on the screen.

Comment: for more info about custom views, read this: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: @stackoverflow : this 'new Larger_Rectangle(getContext());' will create only object. "Do not attach it to any UI elements" ..!!

Comment: You have to attach the rectangle to a parent layout in order for it to work. Create a parent layout. Use addView in the onTouchMethod to add the rectangle to the parent layout

Answer (score 0):

**Step1** - Make a class like below class:

```
public class OnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new OnTouchViewListener());
    }

    private final class OnTouchViewListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            onTouchView();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onTouchView() {
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Step2** - Then in your activity class:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        rectangle = new Rectangle(this);
        setContentView(rectangle);

        rectangle.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(context){
            @Override
            public void onTouchView() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onTouchView();
               //do whatever you want to do
            }

        });
}
```